# Azure IO transfer

Tags: azure, io, disk

We have a VM setup to run SQL server in Azure. we are seeing the disk write is doing like 0.6MBps with WRITE THROUGH during testing. We have tried numerous different this from changing Azure Vm types D series L series etc. We have also created different RAID based disks. is this a limit in Azure that it can do only certain rate for non cached disks than what is advertised as 500MBps.. any help to improve the WRITE THROUGH rate?

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent the blocking issues and to improve the IO performance, we need to:

```
1.Prevent VM level throttling at all cost.
2.Prevent disk level throttling if the application has dependent blocking issue due to the software design. Adding more disks to create a storage pool may help.
```

More information about Azure VM Storage Performance and Throttling, we can refer to: 
[Azure VM Storage Performance and Throttling](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/xiangwu/2017/05/14/azure-vm-storage-performance-and-throttling-demystify/)

According to your issue, as you are using SQL Server, here is an article about how to optimize SQL Server performance in Microsoft Azure Virtual Machine: [Performance best practices for SQL Server in Azure Virtual Machines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-performance)